# Decimal object in python error

Tags: python, decimal

```
>>> from decimal import *
>>> amount = Decimal(0.00114206599999999995793953377898333201301284134387969970703125)
>>> sZ = Decimal(0.0001)
>>> amount.quantize(sZ, rounding=ROUND_DOWN)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
decimal.InvalidOperation: [<class 'decimal.InvalidOperation'>]
>>> 
>>> amount = amount - (amount % sZ)
>>> amount
Decimal('0.001100000000000000052713909626')
>>> amount.quantize(sZ, rounding=ROUND_DOWN)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
decimal.InvalidOperation: [<class 'decimal.InvalidOperation'>]
>>>
```

## I expected to get 0.011

Can anyone explain to me what is going wrong with the python Decimal in my example?

Basically I just want to get a number that's a multitude of sZ (chunksize) and rounded down from the 'amount' (it may never be more).

Comment: `sZ = Decimal(0.0001)` you are using `Decimal` incorrectly, that is, if you care about accuracy. By passing a `float` object, you've already lost precision!

Comment: Hmm. It's unfortunate that the Python 3 version of the `decimal` module does away with the error message. In Python 2 you'd see: `decimal.InvalidOperation: quantize result has too many digits for current context`.

Answer (score 3):

If you DO care about precision, you want do the following:

```
>>> from decimal import *
>>> amount = Decimal('0.00114206599999999995793953377898333201301284134387969970703125')
>>> sZ = Decimal('0.0001')
>>> amount.quantize(sZ, rounding=ROUND_DOWN)
```

The problem is that float have precision issues, and passing the `float` as a parameter to your `Decimal` has already lost precision.